# Laravel download image

Tags: laravel, image, download

I have a function to add an image, and upon successful addition in the database, we have a path like public/images/asd.png. The question is how to make sure that when added to the name of the picture, an ID is added, and we have something like public/images/asd1.png, public/images/asd2.png, etc.

function in Model

```
public function getOriginImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->attributes['image'];
    }

    public function getImageAttribute($value)
    {
        return Storage::exists($value) ? Storage::url($value) : null;
    }
```

function in Controller

```
 if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $blog->image = $file->storeAs('public/images', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of id you can combine time() with image name.

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
       $file = $request->file('image');
       $namewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName(); //Name with extension 'filename.jpg'
       $name = explode('.', $namewithextension)[0]; // Filename 'filename'
       $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); //Extension 'jpg'
       $uploadname = $name. '-' .time() . '.' . $extension;
       $blog->image = $file->storeAs('public/images', $uploadname);
 }
```

Comment: This is a good option, thanks) In fact, the main task is not to have pictures with the same name, because when you delete all pictures with that name are deleted. Let's see if they can offer something else)

Comment: In this way you can keep the file original name as well as the names will be unique. And while displaying the file you can show only file original name (skipping the time from it) to the user. Also don't forget to upvote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes, of course) I just have a little reputation and my vote is not displayed, but it will be recorded